# Catch external service fault exception into wcf riaservice

Tags: wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have wcf service and I used it into ASP.net MVC and WCF RIA service. I am able to catch fault exception into ASP.net MVC but not able to catch into WCF RIA Service.

Following code is for wcf ria service where I use WCF Service

```
public class MyService : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<MyEntities>
{
    try
    {    
        ExternalServiceProxy.SaveData();
    }
    catch(FaultException<ExceptionInfo> ex)
    {
        //Not able to catch faultexception
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Every time catch exception and faultexception information lost
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have the correct type of exception?  In your "catch(Exception ex)" statement, check the specific type of the exception.  It's probably a subclass of Exception, but not a FaultException.